# How to change color of link if url destination page does not exist

Tags: php

I am making a simple wiki-style site.
I have some text in database and want to make links with [link] tag.

```
$text = preg_replace('@\[(.*) (.*)\]@', '<a href="\\1" >\\2</a>', $text);
```

Now I want to change color of the link if the destination page does not exist.
How it can be done?

If I insert php code in preg_replace like this:

```
$text = preg_replace('@[(.*) (.*)]@', '<a href="\\1" class="<?php Wiki::urlchecker($\\1) ?>">\\2</a>', $text); 


it doesnt work, generates:
<a href="link" class="<?php Wiki::urlchecker($link) ?>">Name</a>
```

Comment: The detection whether the page exists, or the color thing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`get_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) to check whether it exists, then use logic to color it with HTML.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/check-if-an-url-exists-in-php) will show you how to check if the URL exists.

[This quetsion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767079/changing-font-color-of-link-text) will show you how to change the color of a link.

Comment: So.. "use logic". Good answer!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I updated with some more.

Comment: You updated with links. But links themselves do not contain information, they simply link to more information. Links are not answers. Please _quote_ the relevant passages of any pertinent information found behind those links.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My answer will contain the same level of effort as the question.

Comment: Well I'm sorry to hear that you have a completely incorrect view of how this website works. -1 from me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, no worries.

Comment: I know how to change color of link and how to check url, but I dont undrestand how to apply it to generated links. If I insert php code in preg_replace like this: $text = preg_replace('@\[(.*) (.*)\]@', '<a href="\\1" class=<?php Wiki::urlchecker($\\1) ?>>\\2</a>', $text); it doesnt work

Comment: What is generating the link?

Comment: generates <a href="sport/football" class="<?php Wiki::urlchecker($sport/football) ?>">Football</a>

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk <?php echo Wiki::wikify($WikiPage->getText()) ?> (symfony framework)

Comment: So you want to change the class in the CSS.

Comment: it doen't matter how to change color, matters how to apply rule to generated links. Links are stored in database as [link name]